# How to check if something belongs to an euclidian space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Sadly I have failed to understand the euclidean space.
For example I have a problem asking me the following:
1. Check that in an euclidean space we have:

$$\left\|x + y\right\|^2  + \left\|x – y\right\|^2 =2( \left\|x\right|^2 +\left\|y|\right\|^2),\  \forall x, y\text{ vectors}$$

Can you please help me understand this kind of problem?
Thank you all for your time!

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking at an inner product space. A normed space that satisfies the parallelogram law you stated above must have an inner product

Comment: Use the definition of what appears in the formula, which is likely that $\left\|x\right\|^2=x\cdot x$. The formula becomes $(x+y)\cdot(x+y)+(x-y)\cdot(x-y)=2(x\cdot x+y\cdot y)$. Use the properties of $\cdot$ to open those parenthesis in the left hand side.

Comment: So after doing as you said the result should look like: **x^2 + xy +yx + y^2 + x^2 - xy - yx + y^2 = 2(x * x + y * y)**       ? @Bettybel

Comment: That's all is needed.